# Different data time zones between R and powerBi Deskop using the same source code in R

Tags: r, powerbi, timezone, powerbi-desktop, gmailr

I work with gmailR and powerBi and I observe that my email data have different message "time" in Rstudio (correct time UTC+1, same that in gmail account) and PowerBi (wrong time, UTC+0) when I using same query code in both tools.

Screen:
[image: Text]
[sorry I don't know how to insert image properly ]

link:
https://ibb.co/TM12Bk1

My query code is based on gmailR, i get specific data in list's from gmail and transform to table (tibble object in R). Then I run code in PowerBi as data source.
I get time from message list, not fuction gm_data (because of cases when this function get null values). Below sample code:

```
gmail_DK<- msgs_meta_DK %>% {
  tibble(
    date = map_chr(., "internalDate")
  )
```

and then I change timestamp to normal data time. Sample code:

```
mutate(date = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(date) /1000, origin="1970-01-01"))
```

I checked regional settings in PowerBi Deskop and it is correct - UTC+1.
I'm in UTC+1 time zone, gmail account is for UTC+1 (this is customer service email, but as I know all customer agent's are too in UTC+1 time zone) and most of message are from and to UTC+1 users.

I can change this difference using PowerQuery or just add hour in my query code in R, but I'm curious why is this difference happen?

Comment: Do power bi and R return the same value of `Sys.timezone()`?

Comment: Yes, function return same time zone in R and powerBi.

Comment: Adding just 1hr will break your code when daylight savings time changes. USe a library instead e.g. `lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), "UTC")` vs `lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), "America/Los_Angeles")`